# How to preview calendar on non-calendar page (2010)?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, calendar

This seems simple. I want to have a preview of the calendar on my site homepage in 2010.

It looks like the only way to do this is to embed the calendar with SharePoint Designer (which then puts a completely pointless table view of all the events) - is there a way to view a quick preview of the calendar on the homepage in a usable form, ie like Google Calendars preview?

Answer (score 0):

When inserting content, use "Form Web Parts" on the SharePoint browser site itself.

After selecting the calendar a preview will be inserted to whatever pane it is in of your site.